# How to install phpMyAdmin tar.gz file when there's no configure file in the extracted folder?

Tags: 20.04, tar, phpmyadmin

[image]

Looks like there's no configure file, so I can't run `./configure` and install the package. Is there any way to solve this problem or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Just extract the `.tar.gz` file in public html directory in Apache and navigate to it in your web browser. It works out of the box. No configuration needed. It needs a web server like Apache to work though.